# How to make an element correctly reset its state and pass props while focusing on the input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, transition

I try to add focus on the input field when the element is mounted.
I use [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cherry-u72fj?file=/src/Header.jsx). When I press button on Header the search bar shows up, I add to it class open because
want my search to move with a help of transition. Search bar starts moving and get to its place and
the focus is applied. it's fine. Then I click "close" button to hide the search bar and it smoothly
return to its place(backwards, to become hidden). It's all right till now. Because after that, the search bar shows up
again and doesn't hide even though I pressed the close button! I expect that

```
onClick={() => { props.setVisibleSearchBar(false) }}
```

will hide my search. By the way, the style for "open" also doesn't
applied when the search appears unexpectevely after the close btn is
clicked(though the search is
visible).

Header.jsx

```
 const Header = () => {
 const [visibleSearchBar, setVisibleSearchBar] = useState(false);
 return (
 <button onClick={() => setVisibleSearchBar(true)}>Show search bar</button>
                                                       
 <Search visibleSearchBar={visibleSearchBar}
                    setVisibleSearchBar={setVisibleSearchBar} />
  );
}
```

Search.jsx

```
 const Header = (props) => {
 const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  let slideRef = useRef('');
  let inputRef = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
    const callback = () => {
        setDisabled(false);
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }
    slideRef.current.addEventListener('transitionend', callback);
    return () => slideRef.current.removeEventListener('transitionend', callback)
}, []);

 return (
    <div
        className={classNames('header-inner__main-search-slide', { open: props.visibleSearchBar })}
        ref={slideRef}>

        <input ref={inputRef}
            disabled={disabled}
            className='header-inner__main-search-slide-field' />
       
        <button
            onClick={() => { props.setVisibleSearchBar(false) }}
            className='header-inner__main-search-slide-close'> CLOSE 
        </button>
    </div >
)
```

Comment: Would like to help, but it seems like the problem is somewhere in your classes or something like that, cause if i remove all the "uknown" parts it looks pretty much ok. Could you create a sandox? Or provide what is "classNames" and your classes used

Comment: @Nikita Chayka I've created a sandbox. Please take a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played with your sanbox, here it is working fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-buck-d2rgx

So you problem was here:

```
    const callback = () => {
        setDisabled(false);
        inputRef.current.focus();
    }
```

You are setting a focus, whenever some transition finishes. But it is incorrect, you have to focus your input only when "open" transition finishes.
It is important, because browser automatically scrolls to the element in focus, that's what was happening in this case, you was hiding input, but then focusing it, so browser "scrolled" it back.

Here is a fixed version of it:

```
  if (slideRef.current.classList.contains("open")) {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
```

Why am i not using `props` here - because, your `useEffect` will be executed only on first render and if i would use `props` here, i would use very first props passed to the component (because of closure). If you don't like to have to check `classList`, other option would be to use state here (move 'open' flag to state)